# How to apply Sobel Filter in frequency domain [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, image-processing

As suggested in the title i wish to apply a sobel filter in freequency domain using matlab.
The main problem here is that the sobel filters matrix size is far less than the original image.
Is there a way i could perhaps apply the filter using the method i used.
I'd prefer not to write more functions or lengthy codes.

```
global curr_freequency;
global trans_freequency;

og_img=getimage(handles.org_img);
[m,n]=size(og_img);

h=size(og_img,1);
w=size(og_img,2);
[x,y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor((w-1)/2),-floor(h/2):floor((h-1)/2));


allitems=handles.SharpFilters.String;
selectedindex=handles.SharpFilters.Value;
selectedItem=allitems{selectedindex};
filt_val=str2num(handles.SharpMaskSize.String);



if(selectedItem=="Butterworth High Pass")
    order=str2num(handles.order_of_filter.String);
    filt=1./(1.+(filt_val./(x.^2+y.^2).^0.5).^(2.*order));
    final_img=curr_freequency.*filt;
    trans_freequency=final_img;
    x=fftshow(final_img);
    axes(handles.intr_freeq);
    imshow(x);
    ifftshow(ifft2(final_img),handles);


elseif selectedItem=="Sobel Filter Vertical"
    sobelvert_filt=fspecial('sobel');
    freeq_filt=fft2(sobelvert_filt);
    applied_filt=curr_freequency.*freeq_filt;
    trans_freequency=applied_filt;
    axes(handles.intr_freeq);
    imshow(fftshow(applied_filt));
    ifftshow(ifft2(applied_filt),handles);

    axes(handles.intr_img);
    imshow(new_img);end;
```

the fftshow function

```
function ret_val = fftshow(f)
fl=log(1+abs(f));
fm=max(fl(:));
ret_val=im2uint8(fl/fm);
```

the ifftshow function

```
  function []=ifftshow(f,handles)
fl=abs(f);
fm=max(fl(:));
show_val=fl/fm;
axes(handles.spatial_rep);
imshow(show_val);
```

Just a thought which i tried implementing maybe my approach to it is wrong, when i fftshift the average values to the center what if i apply a 3x3 filter to the center values of the fftshifted matrix.

i tried doing `padarray(sobelfilter,[floor((h/2)-3),floor((w/2)-3)])`
however it produces wrong results even if i change the reductions i.e -3 to 0 etc.

[image: attempt to pad array]

Comment: "GUIDE, is a graphical user interfaces (GUI) design environment in MATLAB." Your question has nothing to do with MATLAB GUI development. Please check tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: Why would you want to apply the Sobel kernel through the FFT? That would be a waste of computations. In the frequency domain you can easily apply an ideal derivative operator.

Comment: its part of an assignment for my university thats why its required for me to apply sobel kernel , 
could you help me  or direct me onto how would i apply the  ideal derivate operator.